# Count excel values lookup

Tags: excel

Suppose we have cell values:

```
A+B
A+C
A+E+F
A
B+F
```

Now, we have count for A,B,C using countif and E,F are classified into others category, so how can we have the count for others (E,F)

conditions:

1. others will have a "+" sign
2. others will not include A,B,C.

For above example:

count for A:4, B:2, C:1 (using countif), others (E,F): 3 for total, 2 for unique (HOW?)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some formulas for your examples assuming data is in column A:

```
A      =COUNTIF(A:A,"*A*")
Others =SUM(COUNTIF(A:A,{"*+E*","*+F*"}))
Unique =SUM(N(COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&{"A","B","C","D","E","F"}&"*")=1))
```

You could make a list of your letters (A,B,C,D,E,F) in `C1:C6` and fill down COUNTIF formulas in `D1:D6` for the frequencies.

*Follow up*

If you want to find the count of those other than A,B,C in the range `A1:A5` without referring to the values E,F you could try entering:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5&"+",{"","+","A","B","C"},""))*{-2,-1,1,1,1})
```

The formula compares the lengths of substituting the various values in the strings with the string lengths (by substituting nothing). If more letters are added to the list the first value of `-2` should be adjusted so the sum of the array is zero. For searching strings more than one character long, divide by the length of the string eg for `ABC` use `1/3` in the corresponding element of the array and adjust the first value so the array sums to zero.